# Android: RelativeLayout in Scrollview all piled up on the spot

Tags: android

I am currently attempting to create a RelativeLayout, embedded in a Scrollview (so the RelativeLlayout's content can be scrolled vertically). My layout file looks like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_first_day_of_budget_cycle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/first_day_of_budget_cycle"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/settings_divider_one"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/label_first_day_of_budget_cycle"
            layout="@layout/w_divider" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_monthly_income"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/settings_divider_one"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/monthly_income"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/settings_add_income"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/label_monthly_income"
            layout="@layout/w_add" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/settings_divider_two"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/settings_add_income"
            layout="@layout/w_divider" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_monthly_expenses"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/settings_divider_two"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/monthly_expenses"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/settings_add_expenses"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/label_monthly_expenses"
            layout="@layout/w_add" />

        <include
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/settings_add_expenses"
            layout="@layout/w_divider" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And this is how it looks on my phone:

[image]

I tried every possible variation I could think of/find on the net or stackoverflow, without success so far. I am not sure what else I could try or what I am missing here.

I tried varying the values of layout_width and layout_height for the RelativeLayout and the Scrollview, without success. Any hint as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Following ben's suggestion, I removed the includes and the layout then rendered properly. I filed a bug report *[click](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42287&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)* since I am of the opinion, that includes should work with RelativeLayouts embedded in Scrollviews. At least I see no reason why they shouldn't. If my layout contains another mistake that prevents includes from working properly, I guess/hope I'll be replied to accordingly
in the ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I remember, there's some kind of issue with `include` in xml with ScrollViews. Can you try replacing the includes by the actual pieces of xml ?

Comment: I tried what you suggested and that solved the matter :O ! But technically that would mean, that their include feature is not working properly? Do you know if there is a related bug report by any chance? And I really would hate to copy paste all those includes -_- , but either way the mystery is solved :) - thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't tell you any more about this, but if you find a solution to this issue please let me know ;)

Comment: Sure thing :) - I just hope someone is merciful enough to check out that bug report I filed xD

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `LinearLayout` with width and height `fill_parent` instead of `RelativeLayout`.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
          ... your content here
```

Using `RelativeLayout` for vertically aligning elements is a bad idea (slower performance + not easy to read). If you really need a relative layout, you can add it inside the LinearLayout element. Make sure width and height are `fill_parent`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll need a relative layout (the above layout is not the final version). I might be able to switch to LinearLayout, but I would like to know, if its simply not possible to add a RelativeLayout to a Scrollview? And is it really a must to embed the RelativeLayout in a LinearLayout which is then embedded in a Scrollview? That seems very wasteful :( ?

Comment: you are right but I don't have an answer for that w/o spending some time trying. on the other hand, I spent a lot of time on Android performance and RelativeLayout is way harder to calculate simply because of its flexibility. Since you want linear scrolling, it should be suitable for Linear layout. You can still use some smaller relative layouts inside it. But of course if your layout is really complex and using relative layout will decrease layout depth, using it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  The layout won't get too complicated, but without RelativeLayout I'll be required to nest LinearLayouts etc. to achieve the same effect. What irks me, are those includes and why they don't work within a RelativeLayout that's embedded in a ScrollView :S